# google_mlkit_pose_detection in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit

I am a flutter beginner. I want to design a pose detection on flutter by using google_ml_kit,but it failed. I dont know what is the problem.I just see my camera but have no pose painter.

This is all of my flutter code,

main.dart

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pose_detection_app3/home_screen.dart';

late List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(const CameraApp());
}

class CameraApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const CameraApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

It is home_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_pose_detection/google_mlkit_pose_detection.dart';
import 'package:pose_detection_app3/camera_view.dart';
import 'package:pose_detection_app3/painter.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  CustomPaint? customPaint;
  final PoseDetector _poseDetector =
      PoseDetector(options: PoseDetectorOptions());
  bool _canProcess = true;
  bool _isBusy = false;

  void instState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _poseDetector.close();
    _canProcess = false;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Lab321"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: CameraView(
        customPaint: customPaint,
        onImage: (inputImage) {
          processImage(inputImage);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> processImage(InputImage inputImage) async {
    if (!_canProcess) return;
    if (_isBusy) return;
    _isBusy = true;

    final poses = await _poseDetector.processImage(inputImage);
    final painter = PosePainter(poses, inputImage.inputImageData!.size,
        inputImage.inputImageData!.imageRotation);
    setState(() {
      customPaint = CustomPaint(painter: painter);
    });
    _isBusy = false;
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
}
```

It is camera_view.dart

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_commons/google_mlkit_commons.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_pose_detection/google_mlkit_pose_detection.dart';
import 'package:pose_detection_app3/main.dart';

class CameraView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraView({Key? key, this.customPaint, required this.onImage})
      : super(key: key);

  final CustomPaint? customPaint;
  final Function(InputImage inputImage) onImage;

  @override
  State<CameraView> createState() => _CameraViewState();
}

class _CameraViewState extends State<CameraView> {
  CameraController? _controller;
  int _cameraIndex = 0;
  double zoomLevel = 0.0;
  double minzoomLevel = 0.0;
  double maxzoomLevel = 0.0;
  InputImage? inputImage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (cameras.any(
      (element) =>
          element.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back &&
          element.sensorOrientation == 90,
    )) {
      _cameraIndex = cameras.indexOf(
        cameras.firstWhere((element) =>
            element.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back &&
            element.sensorOrientation == 90),
      );
    } else {
      _cameraIndex = cameras.indexOf(
        cameras.firstWhere(
          (element) => element.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back,
        ),
      );
    }

    _startLiveFeed();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _stopLiveFeed();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!_controller!.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }

    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          CameraPreview(_controller!),
          if (widget.customPaint != null) widget.customPaint!,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future _startLiveFeed() async {
    final camera = cameras[_cameraIndex];
    _controller = CameraController(
      camera,
      ResolutionPreset.max,
      enableAudio: false,
    );
    _controller?.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      _controller?.getMinZoomLevel().then((value) {
        zoomLevel = value;
        minzoomLevel = value;
      });
      _controller?.getMaxZoomLevel().then((value) {
        maxzoomLevel = value;
      });
      _controller?.startImageStream(_processCameraImage);
      setState(() {});
    }).catchError((Object e) {
      if (e is CameraException) {
        switch (e.code) {
          case 'CameraAccessDenied':
            print('User denied camera access.');
            break;
          default:
            print('Handle other enrrors.');
            break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  Future _stopLiveFeed() async {
    await _controller?.stopImageStream();
    await _controller?.dispose();
    _controller = null;
  }

  Future _processCameraImage(CameraImage image) async {
    final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
    for (final Plane plane in image.planes) {
      allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
    }
    final bytes = allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();

    final Size imageSize =
        Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());

    final camera = cameras[_cameraIndex];
    final imageRotation =
        InputImageRotationValue.fromRawValue(camera.sensorOrientation);
    if (imageRotation == null) return;

    final inputImageFormat =
        InputImageFormatValue.fromRawValue(image.format.raw);
    if (inputImageFormat == null) return;

    final planeData = image.planes.map(
      (Plane plane) {
        return InputImagePlaneMetadata(
          bytesPerRow: plane.bytesPerRow,
          height: plane.height,
          width: plane.width,
        );
      },
    ).toList();

    final inputImageData = InputImageData(
      size: imageSize,
      imageRotation: imageRotation,
      inputImageFormat: inputImageFormat,
      planeData: planeData,
    );

    inputImage =
        InputImage.fromBytes(bytes: bytes, inputImageData: inputImageData);

    widget.onImage(inputImage!);
  }
}
```

and it is painter.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_pose_detection/google_mlkit_pose_detection.dart';

class PosePainter extends CustomPainter {
  PosePainter(this.poses, this.absoluteImageSize, this.rotation);

  final List<Pose> poses;

  final Size absoluteImageSize;
  final InputImageRotation rotation;

  double translateX(double x, InputImageRotation rotation, Size size,
      Size absoluteImageSize) {
    switch (rotation) {
      case InputImageRotation.rotation90deg:
        return x *
            size.width /
            (Platform.isIOS
                ? absoluteImageSize.width
                : absoluteImageSize.height);
      case InputImageRotation.rotation270deg:
        return size.width -
            x *
                size.width /
                (Platform.isIOS
                    ? absoluteImageSize.width
                    : absoluteImageSize.height);
      default:
        return x * size.width / absoluteImageSize.width;
    }
  }

  double translateY(double y, InputImageRotation rotation, Size size,
      Size absoluteImageSize) {
    switch (rotation) {
      case InputImageRotation.rotation90deg:
      case InputImageRotation.rotation270deg:
        return y *
            size.height /
            (Platform.isIOS
                ? absoluteImageSize.height
                : absoluteImageSize.width);
      default:
        return y * size.height / absoluteImageSize.height;
    }
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final pointPaint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..color = Colors.yellow;

    for (final pose in poses) {
      void paintLine(
          PoseLandmarkType type1, PoseLandmarkType type2, Paint paintType) {
        final PoseLandmark joint1 = pose.landmarks[type1]!;
        final PoseLandmark joint2 = pose.landmarks[type2]!;
        canvas.drawLine(
            Offset(translateX(joint1.x, rotation, size, absoluteImageSize),
                translateY(joint1.y, rotation, size, absoluteImageSize)),
            Offset(translateX(joint2.x, rotation, size, absoluteImageSize),
                translateY(joint2.y, rotation, size, absoluteImageSize)),
            paintType);
      }

      // Draw arms
      paintLine(PoseLandmarkType.leftShoulder, PoseLandmarkType.leftElbow,
          pointPaint);
      paintLine(
          PoseLandmarkType.leftElbow, PoseLandmarkType.leftWrist, pointPaint);
      paintLine(PoseLandmarkType.rightShoulder, PoseLandmarkType.rightElbow,
          pointPaint);
      paintLine(
          PoseLandmarkType.rightElbow, PoseLandmarkType.rightWrist, pointPaint);

      //Draw Body
      paintLine(
          PoseLandmarkType.leftShoulder, PoseLandmarkType.leftHip, pointPaint);
      paintLine(PoseLandmarkType.rightShoulder, PoseLandmarkType.rightHip,
          pointPaint);

      //Draw legs
      paintLine(
          PoseLandmarkType.leftHip, PoseLandmarkType.leftAnkle, pointPaint);
      paintLine(
          PoseLandmarkType.rightHip, PoseLandmarkType.rightAnkle, pointPaint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant PosePainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.absoluteImageSize != absoluteImageSize ||
        oldDelegate.poses != poses;
  }
}
```

Thank you for any ideas you may have!

Comment: Not sure if its too late. But you onImage is only called if processCameraImage function passes all the null check. So easily could have 1 of them values being null and return before calling widget.onImage(). And only when onImage is called, would the painter paint. So... im guessing onImage is not being called? either that, on the painter needs to test? like for trying painting specific points on screen first, before throwing live data, and the match the live data to the points on screen to see if the painter is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ML Kit flutter project: https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit It is not the official one built by Google, but maybe you can try if it works for you.